# Gallery that can be added to a node via node edit page?

Tags: 7, media

I want to have a gallery that I can easily add/edit/delete photos of from a node creation page and if a user adds a gallery it adds it to the node.

So let's say I want to have a gallery on a page, I would add all the title, body, then I would add 3 photos. And that would create a node with a title, body, and a image gallery with 3 photos. Similar to what I can do in wordpress for each page.

Or something that would function similar to what I want.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually use Galleria module to do so:
https://drupal.org/project/galleria

Turns image fields of nodes into Galleria galleries with this JavaScript (JQuery) image gallery.